# Person-years and incidence rate per 1000 person-years

Tags: r, survival-analysis, survival

I am using R, and I have employed the `tbl_uvregression()` function.
However, I would like to include **Person years** and **Incidence rate per 1000 person-years** in the table as well.

```
df3 |>
  select(age, age6, sex, bmi, bmi_cat2,
         scheme_cat, hoscenter_cat1, nation,
         symini_cat3, month_admit, province,death28_cat1,
         favi, dexa, ando, D0Temp, d0temp_38, D0SPO2Pre, d0SPO2Pre_96, 
         exer_postO_3, dd_swabadmit, dd_swabadmit_cat1,timesurvival28_2_year) |>
  mutate(bmi_cat2 = fct_relevel(bmi_cat2, c('18.5 - 22.9', '<18.5', '23.0 - 24.9', '25.0 - 29.9', '30.0 - 34.9', '>=35.0'))) |>
  tbl_uvregression(
    method = coxph,
    y = Surv(timesurvival28_2_year,
             event = death28_cat1 == "Yes"),
    exponentiate = TRUE,
    estimate_fun = purrr::partial(style_ratio, digits = 1),
    pvalue_fun = purrr::partial(style_sigfig, digits = 3)) |>
  add_n(location = "level") |>
  add_nevent(location = "level") |>
  as_gt()
```

Answer (score 0):

Total person-years is simply the sum of the survival times (expressed in years, obviously), and the incidence rate of per 1000 person-years is the number of events, divided by that 1000 times that sum.  Those are not results you get from the Cox model, so probably you can't get them from `tbl_uvregression` alone.